# Create a Moodle user from python application using rest api

Tags: python, rest, web-services, moodle

I am trying to create a Moodle user from my python application using rest api but getting exception 
"Invalid parameter value detected (Missing required key in single structure: courses)" and 
"Missing required key in single structure: courses".

I am making a simple request call with required parameters. My code is below:

```
    import request
    token = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    function='core_user_create_users'
    url = 'http://localhost/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken={0}&wsfunction={1}&moodlewsformat=json'.format(token,function)

    users = {
    "users[0][createpassword]": 1,
    "users[0][username]": "testuser2",
    "users[0][auth]": "manual",
    "users[0][firstname]": "test2",
    "users[0][lastname]": "lastname_test2",
    "users[0][email]": "abc@gmail.com"}

    response= requests.post(url,json=users)
    print(response.content)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: first try to print the status as response.status_code, then if its not started with 2XX then it an error from your side. please paste the status_code here.

Comment: @pavan, 
I have already printed status code. Its 200. Parameters are also exactly same as mentioned in moodle API documentation.

Comment: i am sorry, i taught it was bad request. I was not aware of Moodle.I think you can post your question in https://moodle.org/mod/forum/index.php?id=5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib called moodle moosh (https://moosh-online.com/), with it's is possible create users with command line on linux, perfect to python.